# Regex to turn the straight quotes contained in words like 'cause and 'til into curly quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

These replace function:

```
text = text.replace(/\b'|(\.|\,|\?|\!|\*|---|\.\.\.\s)'/g, '$1&rsquo;')
text = text.replace(/'\b/g, '&lsquo;')
```

Can turn single quotes:

> 'cause 'til it's 'very very' 'broken.'

into curly single quotes:

> ‘cause ‘til it’s ‘very very’ ‘broken.’

But I think you've detected the problem `cause` and `til` should have a right curly quote, not a left curly quote.

How to modify my regex so this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this regex, may be it will help you.

> "'cause it's 'very very' 'broken.'".replace(/(\s|^)(\')(\b)/g, '$1‘$3').replace(/([\b]*)(\')/g, '$1’')

output -

> ‘cause it’s ‘very very’ ‘broken.’

for initial left quotes try this regex -

> .replace(/(\s)(\')(\b)/g, '$1‘$3').replace(/([\b]*)(\')/g, '$1’')

Comment: I think in your output, `‘cause` still has a left quote. It should have a right one.

Comment: its exact same output as you mentioned above. please check it in doc file so you can see that quotes

Comment: Yes, and I mentioned that my output has a problem. Cause should have a right curly quote not a left curly quote.

Comment: .replace(/(\s)(\')(\b)/g, '$1‘$3').replace(/([\b]*)(\')/g, '$1’') try this regex instead of above.

Comment: Oh, it almost worked. It fails with this: `’cause it’s ‘til ‘another case’ ‘broken.’` `cause` is correct but `til` still have a left quote (it should have a righto one).

Answer (score 2):

For your first text.replace:

`text = text.replace(/\b(')|\.(')|(')(?=\w+\s)/g, '$1&rsquo;')`

The key here is the lookahead option (')(?=\w\s) in other words, get me a straight quote that is followed by a string of characters and then a white space character, but ignore everything after the '

Comment: So, I should keep this one? `text = text.replace(/'\b/g, '&lsquo;')` and put after the one you suggested?

Comment: Yeah, that should work just fine.  test it out :-) Depending on your use case you might need to add back in your options for \? and \! since they might be ending punctuation before quotes.  I'm not sure why you were literally searching for * with \* or 4 hyphens in a row, or 4 literal periods in a row followed by a whitespace character?  Those seemed unnecessary to me, but not sure everything you plan to use this for.   If you want to add in ? and ! testing then it would be text = text.replace(/\b(')|\.(')|\!(')|\?(')|(')(?=\w+\s)/g, '$1&rsquo;') for your first one

Comment: This: `el = el.replace(/\b(')|\.(')|(')(?=\w+\s)/g, '$1&rsquo;') el = el.replace(/'\b/g, '&lsquo;')` produces this: `’cause it'’s ’another case'’ ‘broken’`